# How to find series name in Highcharts for mouseOut-event?

Tags: javascript, highcharts, series

I have an mouseOver and mouseOut event for my series, so that the line color of default-grey changes to red when a mouse hovers over it, and back to grey when the mouse is moving on. Now, I'd like to include some kind of {if} routine in order to change the line color from red to grey or black depending on the series name. But what would be the right command to check for the series-name? I tried it with "series.name", with "graph.attr.name", and others, but in vain.

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/luftikus143/f3rgendb/1/).

And the code:

```
$(function () {
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart:
            {
                renderTo: "container",
                type: "line"
            },
            title: 
            {
                text: "Improved Drinking Water Coverage - Percentage of Total Population",
                align: "center",
                y: 20,
                style: 
                {
                    fontFamily: "Arial",
                    fontSize: "20px",
                    fontWeight: "bold",
                    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || "black"
                }
            },
            subtitle:
            {
                text: "200 countries comparison",
                align: "center",
                y: 40,
                style: 
                {
                    fontFamily: "Arial",
                    fontSize: "12px",
                    fontWeight: "",
                    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || "black"
                }
            },
            xAxis: 
            {
                categories: ['1990','1991','1992','1993','1994','1995','1996','1997','1998','1999','2000','2001','2002','2003','2004','2005','2006','2007','2008','2009','2010','2011','2012'], 
                labels:
                {
                    step: 2
                },
                tickWidth: 0,
                endOnTick: true,
                showLastLabel: true
            },
            yAxis: 
            {
                title: 
                {
                    text: "% of Population",
                    align: "high",
                    endOnTick: false,
                    maxPadding: 0.2,
                    rotation: 0,
                    x: 0,
                    y: -20
                },
                min: 0,
                max: 100
            },
            legend:
            {
                enabled: false
            },
            tooltip:
            {
                crosshairs: true,
                useHTML: true,
                headerFormat: '<small>{point.key}</small><br />',
                pointFormat: '<span style="color: #ef0012"><b>{series.name}:</b></span>' + ' {point.y}',
                footerFormat: ''
            },
            plotOptions:
            {
                series:
                {
                    connectNulls: true,
                    shadow: false,
                    lineWidth: 1,
                    marker:
                    {
                        enabled: false
                    },
                    events:
                    {
                        mouseOver: function()
                        {
                            this.graph.attr('stroke', '#FF0000');
                        },
                        mouseOut: function() 
                        {
                            // =========================================================
                            // =========================================================
                            // =========================================================
                            // Here should go what color it goes back to...
                            if {series.name == "Africa"}
                            {
                              this.graph.attr('stroke', 'rgba(255, 100, 100, 0.5)');
                            }
                            else
                            {
                              this.graph.attr('stroke', 'rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.2)');
                            }
                            // =========================================================
                            // =========================================================
                            // =========================================================
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            series: 
            [       {
                        color: 'rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.2)',
                        data: [null,5,5,5,5,5,8,12,15,19,22,26,29,33,36,40,43,47,50,54,57,61,64],
                        name: "Afghanistan"
                    },
                    {
                        color: 'rgba(200, 100, 100, 0.8)',
                        data: [53,53,54,55,56,57,57,58,59,60,60,61,61,62,63,63,64,65,65,66,66,68,68],
                        name: "Africa"
                    }]
        });

});
```

Thanks for any hints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"This" object is serie, so only what you need is refer to the this.name.

```
mouseOver: function () {
                    var color;

                    if(this.name === 'Africa')
                        color = 'green';
                    else
                        color = 'red';

                    this.graph.attr('stroke', color);
 },
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/f3rgendb/2/